# how to make button to not doing repetation of an action

Tags: java

I have a problem with selected button when I press button it do an action that add a table and it select be true and when I press again for remove the table it select false but when I press again the button show three tables and the tables increase as much as I press the button

```
private class ButtonHandler2 implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        boolean j = info.isSelected();
        Component g = t5.SimpleTable1();

        if (j == false) {
            System.out.print(j);
            center.add(g);
            info.setSelected(true);
        } else {
            System.out.print(j);
            center.remove(g);
            center.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.lightGray));
            info.setSelected(false);
        }
        center.revalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `info.isSelected()` do?

Comment: I guess your `remove(g)` doesn't work, becuase that `g` is a new instance. You're not removing what would be supposed maybe?

Comment: info is a button and info.isSelected here is true

Comment: Can you show the code for t5? I think it might be because you are not creating a new instance of t5 (the table). I could be wrong though...

Comment: remove(g) it work doesn't have problem

Comment: Call `repaint()` for your frame, maybe it works?

Comment: thanks for all, I solved the problem was with table as Alvin Bunk said the problem was with table that I add table to panel after that I return panel, but when I just return table without panel it work

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 likely causes that I can think of.

`info.isSelected()` does not return the correct value

`info.setSelected(bool)` does not properly set the value.

`info` is getting reset somewhere else.